# formatted string phone number android

Tags: android, string, format, contactscontract, phone-number

I am currently exporting some of the phone numbers of contacts stored in the Contacts content provider, and I would like to know if something exists to get the 'formated' string for the phone number e.g. instead of xxx-xxx-xxxx => xxxxxxxxxx. for a better DB consistency.

It would be pretty easy with a reg-ex, but i'd like to know if something already exists for this purpose, as the doc. mentions :

```
public static final String NUMBER - Since: API Level 5
The phone number as the user **entered it**.
Type: TEXT - Constant Value: "number"
```

which let's me think a standard format exists somewhere ... ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: wow really no idea anyone ? I guess I'm good to go with regexes ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reg-ex it!  Pretty sure nothing like this exists.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know something like this doesn't exist. I think you will have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you Don't want to use Reg-ex  code than use below code for get this type of formatted number

```
String[] temp=SelectedContactNo.split("-");
        String MoNo="";
        int len=temp.length;
        for(int j=0;j<len;j++)
        {
            MoNo +=temp[j];
        }
```

Now you'll use `MoNo` as formatted String.